# Losing Data every time app is restarted

Tags: sequelize.js

Every time my application is restarted Sequelize drops all my tables in the database and defines them again (including the data), which is troublesome.
Is there any way that only the schema changes can be applied to the database and to do nothing if there is no change?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set logging option to true:   

     sequelize.sync({logging:true}).then(function () {
            console.log("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED SUCCESSFULLY");
        }).catch(function () {
            console.log("CONNECTION REFUSED");
        })


or else you can set the 'force' property to 'false' so that it will not create the table if it is already exists.

sequelize.sync({ force: false}).then(function () {
    console.log("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED SUCCESSFULLY");
}).catch(function () {
    console.log("CONNECTION REFUSED");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const db = new Sequelize('db_name', 'username', 'pwd', {
    dialect: 'sqlite',    
    storage: 'database.sqlite' // <----- this is important to mention, if you want to store your data on file.
});
```

If you don't give storage location then by default it will store data in memory and each time when you restart your server, your data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

use sequelize.sync({ logging: console.log });.It first check whether table exists or not and create tables if not exists.

Answer (score 0):

I am already using it.This is my code:

```
db
  .sequelize
  .sync({ force: false })
  .complete(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err[0];
    } else {
      http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
      });
    }
  });
```

and table code is following:-

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
   });

  return User;
};
```

IT works for first time but lets say after sometime i need one more column in users table lets say name.
then i done this:-

```
 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    firstname: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  return User;
};
```

Then I restarts the server but this time nothing happens in the db....
If I set force attribute : true
then New column is created  but all the data is lost this time.